# Displaying a horizontally centered div above Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display an alert `div` above a Bootstrap modal. The div should be centered horizontally in relation to the modal.

This following code (or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zr6snzu/2/)) is what I did. My problem is that the `shortMessage` text is being wrapped for no need. How can I fix it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
    $("#myButton").click(function(){
     var shortMessage = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
        var LongMessage = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \
                           Nullam iaculis consequat risus sit amet feugiat. \
                           Sed nec arcu quis tellus pretium malesuada id fringilla mi.";
        DisplayFadingAlert(shortMessage);
        setTimeout(function(){
         DisplayFadingAlert(LongMessage);
        }, 2000);
    });
});

function DisplayFadingAlert(message)
{
    $fadingAlert = $("<div />", {
        "class": "alert alert-success fading-message",
        "text": message,
    });
    $fadingAlert.appendTo($("body"));

    var MARGIN = 5;
    var modalWidth = $(".modal-content").width();
    var fadingAlertMaxWidth = parseInt(modalWidth - (MARGIN * 2));
    var fadingAlertWidth = $fadingAlert.width();
    
    if (fadingAlertWidth >= fadingAlertMaxWidth) 
      fadingAlertWidth = fadingAlertMaxWidth; 
    var modalLeft = $(".modal-content").offset().left;
    var fadingAlertLeft = modalLeft + ((modalWidth - fadingAlertWidth) / 2);

    $fadingAlert.css({
        "left": fadingAlertLeft,
        "width": fadingAlertWidth,
        "max-width": fadingAlertMaxWidth
    });

    $fadingAlert.fadeIn(300).delay(1500).fadeOut(600);;
}
```

```css
.fading-message {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        I'm a modal body
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="myButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
          Display Alert
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what does it mean wrapped , you mean regenerated again ?

Comment: @bRIMOs, what I mean is that the word "amet" in `shortMessage` goes down to a new line, though it shouldn't

Comment: That's because of the width you are setting in the `DisplayFadingAlert` function. Just setting the max-width should be fine. Can you try removing the width or setting `width: auto`?

Comment: @Shashank, when I do it, the horizontal centering brakes. You can see it happenning clearly [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6zr6snzu/5/).

Comment: Okay! Let me get back to you with a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a demo: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zr6snzu/9/)

**Fix:**

`fadingAlertWidth` didn't include the outer padding and border which resulted in wrapping of the text.

**Relevant code:**

```
var fadingAlertWidth = $fadingAlert.width()+32; // padding of 15px on the left and right and border of 1px each
```

And as mentioned in the comments, just the `max-width` is set and `width:auto`

Additionally, `fadingAlert` messages were being appended to the body **BUT** never being removed. I've added the following line in the `DisplayFadingAlert` function to fix this issue:

```
$('body div.alert.fading-message').remove();
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I see, I forgot the `.alert` class padding and border. Thanks. For completeness, Here's a non hard-coded code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zr6snzu/11/)

Comment: Nice! Glad to help! :)